# Check if point is near a linestring Spatialite

Tags: spatialite, linestring

I have a LINESTRING made of two points start point and end point in spatialite.

```
UPDATE points SET road_geometry = GeomFromText('LINESTRING(24.889142 67.196188, 
24.889673 67.196579)',4326) where name='name';
```

and Now, I want to check that if any other point is within that line string or how far the point is from the LINESTRING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either ST_Distance or PtDistWithin (see [documentation](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html#p13)).  With the former you can test for the distance of your points and then select based on some distance criteria.

If you are wanting to test whether a point lies exactly on your line you could try doing an Intersection or use ST_Contains.  My only hesitation with these approaches is that, because a point has no area or length, normal rounding errors within floating point coordinates may give false negatives, so ST_Distance and then a selection based on some acceptable threshold may be better in this case.

Comment: ST_Intersects finds also if point lies exactly on line. The SQL functions link is good now but this one stays up-to-date automatically http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

Comment: st_intersects works fine when point lies exactly on line, but what when  the point is few metres away from line?Maybe I also have to check for distance or there is any other approach....the linestring is actually a road and i want to know that if the user is on the road or not.

Comment: Hence my comment about floating point rounding.  Note that in my reply I advocate ST_Distance for your use-case.

Comment: what if i create a buffer around the point and then check for intersection?Which approach is better?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do after you have found your points.